# Where to download Python 3 modules

Tags: python-3.x, module, web-scraping

I am learning from ["Automate the boring stuff with Python"](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/), and in [Chapter 11 - Web Scraping](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter11/), it started with four modules:

"Webbroser, 
Requests, 
Beautiful Soup,
Selenium."

I tried a lot to download those modules from Pypi, but I couldn't find them.

Would you please tell me where to get them, Thanks!

Comment: I'm guessing "Webbroser" is supposed to be the `webbrowser` module, which is in the standard library. The others should all be available on Pypi, though you probably want the `beautifulsoup4` package instead of the older version named `beautifulsoup`. Try running `python -m pip install requests beautifulsoup4 selenium`. I also see in [the online version of chapter you're reading](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter11/) that there are installation instructions for each module just before you use it.

Comment: Thanks for correcting! I'll remember that. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by "Webbroser" you mean `webbrowser`, then it is in the standard library.

The others have PyPi pages:

- [Requests](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests/)
- [BeautifulSoup](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/beautifulsoup4)
- [Selenium](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium)

---

You can also install it with `pip`.

Linux:

```
pip install requests beautifulsoup4 selenium
```

Windows:

```
python -m pip install requests beautifulsoup4 selenium
```

Comment: Thanks, you help me a lot.

Comment: @MatthewXie No problem. Glad to help :-)